# Insert List<> and check for duplicates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

im trying to build an application that reads news RSS feeds, and then puts the elements in a database. From which i later on can add statistics to each of the topics "titles".

I figured the best way to go at this is by make a script that parse the xml-data into a List, and then insert this list into database, and which it at the same time checks for duplicates?

Or do you have any smarter way?

Main question, How do I insert a List to database and at the same time prevent duplications? Thank you

Comment: What do you consider a duplicate? Duplicate Topics from the RSS feed or Duplicate Topic Rows in the database? Im assuming you database should be able to store multiple rows per topic.

Comment: Duplicate topics from the RSS feed. Every topic is unique so the only thing i want to check against is the current database so i dont have duplicate posts.

Comment: Then I believe cost has a nice answer to solve for your use case. This will get you constant time lookup for checking duplicates. Just make sure that the key to the hashset is the topic.

Comment: Why not insert into the database one record at a time? Finding and rejecting duplicates is what databases are good at.

Comment: If you're using SQL server (as your tags suggest), why not add [unique constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190024.aspx) to your database and avoid having to check for duplicates yourself? The table index is very good at checking for duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is how you want to do it, instead of a List, look into using a [Hashset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If there are a lot of elements in your news feed, a `hashset` can tell you quickly if it exists in the collection already or not. In pseudo code it would basically be:

```
HashSet.Add(Element);
```

Duplicate records are automatically ignored (`Add` will return true if the item is added, and false if it already existed).

Comment: `Add` do not throw if the element is already in the set, so `Contains` is unnecessary in this case.